# How can I make Sinatra use CSRF Authenticity tokens?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, csrf

I'm building a simple app in ruby using the Sinatra framework. It's mainly "get" based - most requests will be for listing data. However there are a couple of key screens in the app that will collect user input. I want to ensure the app is as safe as I can make it, and currently, trying to find how to implement the kind of authenticity tokens that you get in a Rails form?

Where I've got to:
Well, I know I need the tokens for csrf, but I'm unsure if I need to generate them myself or if Sinatra can do it for me - I've looked through the docs and they say that Sinatra is using Rack Protection, however, I can't find any example code for it and can't seem to figure out how to get it going - any help apprectiated - thanks!

Comment: Is it default now? BTW to disable sinatra CSRF    so ajax works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42454418/how-to-add-access-control-allow-origin-headers-to-api-response-in-ruby/42456805#comment100478921_42456805  (and i'd only do this for a small demo application) . otherwise maybe something like $.ajaxSetup({.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098239/post-422-unprocessable-entity-in-rails-due-to-the-routes-or-the-controller/56821525#56821525
 but somehow adapted for sinatra

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the [`rack_csrf`](https://github.com/baldowl/rack_csrf) gem. Install it with

```
gem install rack_csrf
```

The `rack_csrf` gem has a [Sinatra example](https://github.com/baldowl/rack_csrf/tree/master/examples/sinatra). Below is a simpler example adapted from [this page](http://emilloer.com/2011/01/15/preventing-csrf-in-sinatra/) (seems offline. [Archived version](http://web.archive.org/web/20110513020511/http://emilloer.com/)):

```
require "rack/csrf"

configure do
  use Rack::Session::Cookie, :secret => "some unique secret string here"
  use Rack::Csrf, :raise => true
end
```

Using `enable :sessions` instead of `use Rack::Session::Cookie ...` will also work in most cases (see Bill's comment).

In your view, you can get the token (or the tag) with the `Rack::Csrf.csrf_token` and `Rack::Csrf.csrf_tag` methods. If this appears lengthy, you may want to define a helper along the lines of:

```
helpers do
  def csrf_token
    Rack::Csrf.csrf_token(env)
  end

  def csrf_tag
    Rack::Csrf.csrf_tag(env)
  end
end
```

Small example using the helper method:

```
<form method="post" action="/tweet">
  <%= csrf_tag %>
  <input type="text" name="message"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit a tweet!"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Here is the link from Google's cache: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Femilloer.com%2F2011%2F01%2F15%2Fpreventing-csrf-in-sinatra%2F&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=9bbc30a1cd66fab9&biw=1424&bih=820&ion=1

Comment: @elevine thank you! i updated my answer with a summary of the post in case it eventually disappears from google's cache, too.

Comment: Google Cache did go down. Thank you for saving it here.

Comment: Internet Archive != google http://web.archive.org/web/20110513020511/http://emilloer.com/

Comment: It should be noted that `enable :sessions` is not similar but not the same as `use Rack::Session::Cookie`. The former will set you up with an automatic, no-thinking-required session and the latter lets you do things like set expirations on sessions. Be sure to choose the option that works best for your scenario. That said, they'll both do the job in the context of this question's answer. http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#sessions

Comment: How does Rack::Csrf compare to Rack::Protection::AuthenticityToken?  They seem to serve the same purpose, yet R::P::AT claims to be "compatible" with Rack::Csrf, though I don't know what that means.

Answer (score 0):

When same erb view is rendered, in a case where credentials are invalid while logging in. now after the render on submit it throws the error.
    `Rack::Csrf::InvalidCsrfToken at /login`
    `Rack::Csrf::InvalidCsrfToken`

Do we need to do a redirect in place of render to make this work? because in render the old csrf token is still in place. in a complete redirect we have a new token generated.