# Rails: POST 422 (Unprocessable Entity) in Rails? Due to the routes or the controller?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, httprequest

I'm trying to give users on my website "points" or "credits" for tweeting about out the brand name.

I have the fancy twitter widget on the appropriate view...

```
<p><a  href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="Check Out This Awesome Website Yay" data-via="BrandName" data-hashtags="ProductName">Tweet</a>
<div id="credited"></div>
<script>window.twttr = (function (d, s, id) {
  var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src= "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function (f) { t._e.push(f) } });
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
</script>
```

I have the JS all written up and pretty....

```
function creditTweet() {
  $.post(
    "/credit_tweet",
    {},
    function(result) {
      var text;
      if (result.status === "noop") {
        text = "Thanks for sharing already!";
      } else if (result.status === "ok") {
        text = "5 Kredit Added";
      }
      $("#credited").html(text);
    }
  );
}

$(function() {
  twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
    window.twttr.events.bind('tweet', creditTweet);
  }); 
});
```

Now the problem is either in the controller OR in the routes (where I'm posting). I think the routes are fine because the POST is almost working, because this is the description of the error on wikipedia - "422 Unprocessable Entity (WebDAV; RFC 4918)
The request was well-formed but was unable to be followed due to semantic errors."

So, do you guys see anything wrong with my ruby code in the controller?

```
class SocialKreditController < ApplicationController
    TWEET_CREDIT_AMOUNT = 5

  def credit_tweet
    if !signed_in?
      render json: { status: :error }
    elsif   current_user.tweet_credited
        Rails.logger.info "Not crediting #{ current_user.id }"
        render json: { status: :noop }
      else
        Rails.logger.info "Crediting #{ current_user.id }"
        current_user.update_attributes tweet_credited: true
        current_user.add_points TWEET_CREDIT_AMOUNT
        render json: { status: :ok }
      end
  end
end
```

And in my routes.rb, it's pretty straight forward, so I doubt there's anything wrong here...

```
  get 'social_kredit/credit_tweet'
  post '/credit_tweet' => 'social_kredit#credit_tweet'
```

Where oh where is this error? I clearly don't know smack about HTTP requests.

Comment: IME rails usually returns 422 when an ActiveRecord object fails to update/save. What does your log say?

Comment: Looks like ....

Started POST "/credit_tweet" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-24 00:34:53 -0500
Processing by SocialKreditController#credit_tweet as */*
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken - ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken:

Comment: can you post the log from rails server with lines which show this error? Also, why you have two routes `get` and `post` pointing to same method?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I got it working!

I added a...

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```

to the controller.

The issue was found when checking out the logs and seeing that the CSRF token could not be verified.

Comment: You may also want to check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203304/warning-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-rails) for a solution which doesn't require disabling the csrf token check.

Comment: thanks @ihaztehcodez  - this skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token is only used on a controller that is necessary for users after being signed in. Are there any major reasons why I may want to use the AJax solution provided in that link over this little snippet?

Comment: @piratetone : Yes, that reason is security.

Comment: [The rails security guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf) does a good job of explaining csrf.  In general, you should not disable the csrf check without a good reason (callbacks from a third-party API for instance).  In this case it is completely within your power to make the csrf check happy and that is the best thing to do.

Comment: This is the solution!

Comment: Turning off security is the solution?

Comment: Tokens for everyone yei!

Answer (score 6):

ihaztehcodez(who was last active in 2016 so it won't help nudging him to post an answer)  mentions that the `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` technique is not so secure 'cos you lose forgery protection.

they mention that the best/secure/'better practise', solutions are mentioned here [WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203304/warning-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-rails)

e.g.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
```

or

```
$.ajax({ url: 'YOUR URL HERE',
  type: 'POST',
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
  data: 'someData=' + someData,
  success: function(response) {
    $('#someDiv').html(response);
  }
});
```

or

putting this within an ajax request

```
headers: {
  'X-Transaction': 'POST Example',
  'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
},
```

Answer (score 2):

Same problem I faced.
It sorts out after adding

**skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token**

at the top of your controller where your JS is calling or sending data.

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
    def create
    end
end
```

as shown in code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

I had this challenge when working on a **Rails 6** API-only application.

I followed the answer here - [Rails: How to implement protect_from_forgery in Rails API mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66338666/10907864) to implement protect_from_forgery in Rails API mode, but I was still having the `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity` error  followed by the `422 Unprocessable Entity` error when I send **post** requests from **Postman**:

```
Started POST "/api/v1/programs" for ::1 at 2021-02-23 18:42:49 +0100
Processing by Api::V1::ProgramsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"program"=>{"name"=>"Undergraduate", "code"=>"UD", "affiliate_status"=>false, "motto"=>"Our motto is ...", "description"=>"This is a new program", "school_id"=>1}}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
  TRANSACTION (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/programs_controller.rb:27:in `create'
  Baserecord::School Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "schools".* FROM "schools" WHERE "schools"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/programs_controller.rb:27:in `create'
  TRANSACTION (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/programs_controller.rb:27:in `create'
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 30ms (Views: 0.8ms | ActiveRecord: 6.9ms | Allocations: 13172)
```

**Here's I solved it**:

The issue was caused by a validation error from my models. A validation I added to the model for the controller I was calling was failing. I had to check the **Body** of the response returned by Postman after making the request to find the error:

```
{
    "affiliate_status": [
        "can't be blank"
    ]
}
```

Once I fixed the error following this answer - [Rails: Validation fails for ActiveRecord in setting a random Boolean Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66338371/10907864), everything worked fine afterward.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 1):

a 422 can happen when updating a model in a POST request:

e.g. `@user.update!(email: nil)` in `users#update` will make a 422 if there is a validation on email like `validates :email, presence: true`

Answer (score 0):

If you're including Rails meta data in the HTML header with `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` it'll generate the following.

```
<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="ihwlaOLL232ipKmWYaqbSZacpJegQqooJ+Cj9fLF2e02NTQw7P/MfQyRuzruCax2xYWtEHWsb/uqiiZP6NWH+Q==" />
```

You can pull the CRSF token from the meta data and pass it into your async request.
Using the native js `fetch` method you can pass it in as a `x-csrf-token` header.

This is a trimmed onSave handler for a React component that enhances a standard Rails form.

```
  onSaveHandler = (event) => {
    const data = "Foo Bar";
    const metaCsrf = document.querySelector("meta[name='csrf-token']");
    const csrfToken = metaCsrf.getAttribute('content');
    fetch(`/posts/${this.props.post_id}`, {
      method: "PUT",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        content: data
      }),
      headers: {
        'x-csrf-token': csrfToken,
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'accept': 'application/json'
      },
    }).then(res => {
      console.log("Request complete! response:", res);
    });
  }
```

Forgery protection is a good idea. This way we stay secure and don't mess with our Rails configuration.

Using `gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.5'` & `"react": "^16.8.6",`