# Rails: Validation fails for ActiveRecord in setting a random Boolean Attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, rails-models, seeding

I am trying to save a boolean value in a model by seeding it

**20151130014042_create_duty_statuses.rb**

```
class CreateDutyStatuses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :duty_statuses, :id => false  do |t|
      t.string :id, limit: 36, primary: true, null: false
      t.string :remark, :limit => 256
      t.boolean :active, :required => true, default: false
      t.string :employee_id,limit: 36, :required => true
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

**duty_status.rb**

```
class DutyStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  include UUIDHelper
  belongs_to :employee
  validates_length_of :remark , maximum: 256, message: "description must be less than 256 characters"
  validates_presence_of :active
end
```

**seeds.rb**

```
 dutyStatus = DutyStatus.new(remark: Faker::Lorem.sentence, employee: myEmployee)
 dutyStatus.active = [false,true].sample
 dutyStatus.created_at = rand(720..72000).hours.ago
 dutyStatus.save
```

If I use

```
dutyStatus.active = [false,true].sample
```

This does not record anything in the database. neither does 0,1 or "true", "false"; unless I do like an implicit true, it saves the value 1; but I need random boolean values. Here's the error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Active can't be blank
```

How do I save random values in the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you set the active as a lambda object and then call it on setting value?

Try this out:

```
active = -> { [false,true].sample }
dutyStatus = DutyStatus.new(remark: Faker::Lorem.sentence, employee: myEmployee)
dutyStatus.active = active.call
dutyStatus.created_at = rand(720..72000).hours.ago
dutyStatus.save
```

I think it also has something to do with validating the presence of boolean field. I think you should validate the inclusion of `active`:

```
validates :active, inclusion: { in: [true, false] }
```

Comment: nope still getting ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Active can't be blank

Comment: @James, Ok, I think you should validate the inclusion of active (feels like I had similar issue with boolean field some time ago). `validates :active, inclusion: { in: [true, false] }`. Try it out

Answer (score 2):

[Andrey Deineko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34153347/10907864) was very helpful. Just to add to it.

I had a **boolean** field that I was trying to validate in my **Rails 6** application using

```
validates :affiliate_status, presence: true
```

But it was failing. I was getting the error:

```
{
    "affiliate_status": [
        "can't be blank"
    ]
}
```

**Here's how I solved it**:

I had to change the validation from:

```
validates :affiliate_status, presence: true
```

to:

```
validates :affiliate_status, inclusion: { in: [true, false] }
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**