# Ruby 2.6.0 Invalid authenticity token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-2.6

My code shows "Invalid Authenticity" instead of "missing template". What do I need to change in the program to get the "missing template error"? 
[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9sGi.png) [img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faL93.png) [img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrLPC.png) [errorImg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFj2L.png)

A reference to the entire program is here below:
[link to github resp](https://github.com/LawLeyenda/re-former3)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

new.html.erb below:

## New view

```
<form action="/users" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <label for="username">Username:</label><br>
  <input id="username" name="user[username]" type="text" /><br>
  <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
  <input id="email" name="user[email]" type="text" /><br>
  <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
  <input id="password" name="user[password]" type="text" /><br>
  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>"> 
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

route.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

Comment: Please add the code to your question (instead of images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to do protect_from_forgery with config/application.rb

```
config.api_only = true
```

[Here is your situation described](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42844747/4453714)

If you will use your app as API, you should regenerate it like

```
$ rails new my_api --api
```

And if you need more security, you can store your tokens in other places(not cookie or session) - for example you can use JWT Tokens.
For more security you can also use [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) gem
And if you accidently removed assets and dont want to use API, you can set this config to false

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="form_authenticity_token %>">
```

This should actually be:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>">
```

Since otherwise the authenticity token that is used to prevent cross site request forgery attacks will just be 'form_authenticity_token %>'  instead of the real token.

Comment: sorry. My code is that. I accidentally reformatted the code wrong when posting. I still get the error.