# 422 unprocessable entity, when trying to send user sign up details to rails api

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, api, devise

I'm trying to send JSON from react front end to the rails API with devise to sign up a new user. I have already successfully added a new user with insomnia by a HTTP post request with JSON and in this format below, receiving back a token

```
{
  "user": {
    "id": 7,
    "email": "newuser@email.com",
    "username": "brannewuser12",
    "subject": null,
    "teacher": null,
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6NywiZXhwIjoxNjM0MTIyMTA2fQ.ZnwCLcTtIxykk_n9YCHny_E7B1CUMlb41oF4Ti0NbUY"
  }
}
```

when I try to use react to do the same I get an unprocessable entity 422 error. below is what is console logged for the user variable

```
user:
email: "michaelmcloughlin9@gmail.com"
password: "mike321"
password_confirmation: "mike321"
subject: "maths"
teacher: "false"
```

here is the javascript, I don't understand what is going wrong, I would appreciate any advice , thank you for reading.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'
//  import axios from 'axios'

export default function Signup() {
  // const teacher = false
  const [teacher, setUserType] = useState(false);
  const [subject, setSubject] = useState(" ");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("email");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("password");
  const [password_confirmation, setConfirmedPassword] = useState("confirm password");
  const username = "thisuser"

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const user = {user:{email, subject, password, password_confirmation, username, teacher,}}
    console.log(user)

    fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/users', {
      mode: 'no-cors',
      method: 'POST', 
      headers: { "Content-Type": "json"},
      body: JSON.stringify(user)
    }).then(() => {
      console.log(user)
    })
  }

  
  return (
    <div className="signup-form">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          <input 
            type="radio"
            value={teacher}
            onChange={(e) => setUserType(e.target.value)}
            />
            Student
        </label>
        
        <label>
          <input 
            type="radio"
            value={teacher}
            onChange={(e) => setUserType(e.target.value)}
            />
            Tutor
        </label>

        <label>Subject</label>
          <input 
            type="text"
            required
            placeholder=" "
            onChange={(e) => setSubject(e.target.value)}
          /><br/>
        <label>Email address</label>
        <input 
          type="text"
          required
          placeholder="email"
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        /><br/>
        <label>New password</label>
        <input 
          type="text"
          required
          placeholder="choose password"
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        /><br/>
        <label>Confirm password</label>
        <input 
          type="text"
          required
          placeholder="confirm password"
          onChange={(e) => setConfirmedPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: using axios.post rather than fetch which seems to automatically handle the JSON formatting

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `JSON.Stringify()` ?

```
fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/users', {
      mode: 'no-cors',
      method: 'POST', 
      headers: { "Content-Type": "json"},
      body: JSON.stringify(user)
    }).then(() => {
      console.log(user)
    })
```

Comment: ahh sorry yes that was in the code already i forgot to add it back in to paste on here. but yeah it doesn't work with that either

Comment: it might be backend issue. -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098239/rails-post-422-unprocessable-entity-in-rails-due-to-the-routes-or-the-contro